# Execute action after confirm a modal (in directive)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a directive to open a modal as confirmation, before do some actions. The modal result function fires, but i can't execute the ngConfirmClick action.

```
app.directive('ngConfirmClick', function( $modal ) {

    return {

        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind('click', function() {

                var message = attrs.ngConfirmMessage;
                var action = attrs.ngConfirmClick;

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({

                    templateUrl: 'views/modals/confirmClick.html',
                    controller: 'ConfirmClickCtrl',
                    resolve: {

                        message: function() { 

                            return message;

                        }

                    }

                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function() {

                   scope.$apply(action);

                });

            });

        }

    }

});


<button ng-confirm-message="Really delete user?" ng-confirm-click="delete(user)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
```

Any idea why the apply function wont work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attribute` from mark-up is always interpreted as a string - nothing fancy here.

The easiest way to pass callback function to a directive is as follows:

```
app.directive('ngConfirmClick', function( $modal ) {

    return {

    // ... other options

    scope : {
        action : "&ngConfirmClick" // mind -&- at the beginning
    },

    link : funciton(scope, ...){

         scope.action();

    }
});
```

[_P_L_N_K_R_](http://plnkr.co/edit/IRfugB5Y89YwvnEKOggw?p=preview)

Comment: thats what I'am looking for! Thank you!